# Fractional powers of Markov generators

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-processes, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

Let $H$ be the generator of a symmetric Markov semigroup on  $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n).$ Why the fractional power $H^\alpha$ (defined on a proper domain) with $0 < \alpha < 1$ turn out to be the generator of another symmetric Markov semigroup?

I am trying to use the integral formula

$$ s^\alpha =  {\sin(\pi \alpha) \over \pi} \int_{0}^\infty t^{\alpha-1} {s \over t+s} \: dt \quad \mbox{for all } 0 < \alpha < 1. $$

Do you have any hint?

Comment: If $H$ is a symmetric Markov generator, $(I-H)^n$ is a transition operator for every nonnegative integer $n$ hence the expansion $$H^\alpha=(I-(I-H))^\alpha=\sum_{n\geqslant0}(-1)^n{\alpha\choose n}(I-H)^n$$ with negative coefficients for every $n\geqslant1$ if $\alpha$ is in $(0,1)$, proves that every such $H^\alpha$ is a symmetric Markov generator.